# Is "10 P.M. last night" redundant?

Tags: time, redundancy

I know that it's redundant to say things like "8:00 A.M. in the morning" or "6:00 P.M. at night." But what if you want to specify that you're talking about a specific night, such as last night? For example:

> We met them at the airport at 10:00 P.M. last night.

Would this sentence be redundant? It seems strange to have both "P.M." and "night," but leaving out "last night" would change the meaning of the sentence, since it would no longer make clear what day this occurred.

Comment: We met them at ten o'clock last night.

Comment: We met them at the airport yesterday at 10:00 p.m.

Comment: OR We met them at ten last night (at the airport).

Comment: Those all sound much better! I feel silly for not thinking of any of those. I was focusing so much on the "last night" part, I didn't think of taking away the "P.M." part.

Comment: Yes, it is redundant, and there are many ways to remove the redundancy. But it's also OK to leave it as is. Not a big deal.

Comment: We met them last night, at 2200 hours.

Comment: @Nicole: I wouldn't judge anyone for saying "10 pm last night". But you could say "last night at 10".

Comment: I have always heard people say something like "it's 8 am in the morning, what are you doing at my house" in an annoyed voice

Comment: @jxh Although it's quite common among Italian speakers e.g. "le ore ventidue", no native English speaker (who isn't in the military) says the time using the 24 hour clock e.g:  "We met them at twenty-two hundred hours" this is accurate, and unambiguous, but it's not idiomatic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree it is not idiomatic. 24 clock on digital devices are becoming more popular, however.

Comment: Note that what's idiomatic will depend to a large degree on whether you observe 12 or 24-hour time.  24-hour time is, I understand, routinely used in some parts of Europe.

Comment: There are situations where too much redundancy is not enough, and when to meet someone at the airport is one of them.

Comment: In general, I shun the use of "AM" or "PM" in spoken conversation. There is always a more natural way of saying it, and often a more meaningful one. If were to say "we picked them up last night at 10", versus "we picked them up yesterday evening at 10", I'm actually communicating a little bit about my stance on how late 10PM is to me. Likewise, "let's meet before work at 7", "let's do dinner at 9?", "do you want to go on an afternoon ride, say 3 o'clock?"

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the original.  It states that the meeting occurred at 10 PM and then goes on to qualify that to last night (vs, say, last Tuesday).  The fact that "PM" and "night" are redundant is of no consequence -- not a violation of syntax or semantics, and not terribly contrary to standard idiom.  (Note that "at 2200 last night" is equally redundant, but I doubt that many would insist that "last night" be changed to "yesterday" to eliminate the redundancy.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly there are ways of phrasing it (as evidenced in the comments) that eliminate any perceived redundancy with "p.m." and "night" both being present, but this sort of phrasing would be fairly common in ordinary conversation as people construct a sentence "on the fly", adding the relevant bits as it occurs to them.
Indeed, even "10 a.m. this morning", despite its obvious redundancy, would be a very common utterance from someone who, after giving the time of an event, decided that they wanted to also specify the day.

Comment: Good answer. One of the most succinct ways to convey the information is to say "We met them at the airport at 10:00 p.m. yesterday." But in the comments beneath the original post, no one has suggested that wording; and the reason, I think, is related to the reason people fall into the redundancy of "10 p.m. last night"—namely, that to a hearer "yesterday" (or "last night") at the end of the sentence makes a much bigger impression than "p.m." does one word earlier. Even though "10 p.m." clearly signifies "night," the "yesterday" is somehow unnerving. "Did he say "10 a.m. or 10 p.m. yesterday?"

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor additional thing; it's less true in the given example given but there are times of day where this would clear up some ambiguity:

- "4am this morning" implies that I got up very early
- "4am last night" implies that I stayed up very late

10pm is of course less ambiguous, but there's still a small amount of implied meaning:

- "I worked until **10pm *last night***" - I saw 10pm as part of my "night". A listener might imagine I was then ready to go straight to sleep
- "I worked until **10pm *yesterday evening***" - I saw 10pm as part of my "evening". A listener might imagine I had an hour or two doing other activities before going to sleep